# quiero mantenerme en la misma pagina

Tags: ajax

como puedo mantenerme en la misma pagina con ajax?

mi ajax es

```
$('#add-user').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/evaluacion/usuariosSeleccionados",
      data: { 
              fact: JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem("evaluacion")),
              seleccionados: JSON.stringify(yourArray)
            },
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "text",
      success: function(data) {
        document.open("text/html", "replace");                          
        document.write(data);
        document.close();
        window.location.href="/evaluacion/agregarUsuarios"// esto hago para que se quede en la misma pagina

      },
      error: function(err) {
        var msg = 'Status: ' + err.status + ': ' + err.responseText;

      }
    });
```

**y mi link es**

```
a(href="" id='add-user' class='btn btn-primary') agregar usuarios
```

> window.location.href="/evaluacion/agregarUsuarios"// esto hago para
>   que se quede en la misma pagina

***esta bien que use window.location.href???***

Comment: Prueba usando event.preventDefault().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que hay dos cosas que puede que te fallen. Al hacer click en la etiqueta `<a />` estás llamando a una función y te falta un `event.preventDefault();` que evita que se propague el `href` de la etiqueta. Y por otro lado veo que estás reescribiendo el documento:

```
document.open("text/html", "replace");                          
document.write(data);
document.close();
```

Si necesitas imprimir el resultado del `ajax` te recomiendo que hagas algo así:

```
var result = document.getElementById('result');
result.innerHTML = data;
```

**En tu código:**

```js
$('#add-user').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/evaluacion/usuariosSeleccionados",
    data: { 
      fact: JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem("evaluacion")),
      seleccionados: JSON.stringify(yourArray)
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#result').html(data);
    },
    error: function(err) {
      var msg = 'Status: ' + err.status + ': ' + err.responseText;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a href="" id="add-user" class="btn btn-primary">
  Agregar usuarios
</a>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: document.write es un error , por favor cambialo por innerHTML